# The user entered date changes when stored in mongodb, how to store it in original state?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, web-development-server

I am making a practice project on a restaurant website that has an option of table reservation. The date-time entered in the form by the user changes when stored in MongoDB due to the UTC time-saving system of MongoDB. In India, the time is UTC+5:30 so it changes accordingly. How do I modify the time entered by the user so that it can be saved in its original state? I am new to MongoDB and mongoose so I am not well versed with the techniques which can be used.

Eg: Suppose the user entered the date-time as **26-5-22 8:27 pm**

In mongodb, it saves as **ISO(2022-05-26T14:57:00Z)**

MY js code for MongoDB is below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
async function main(){
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/HamdansEatery');
}
const reservationSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    tel: Number,
    email: String,
    no_of_persons: Number,
    date_time: Date
})

const Reservation = mongoose.model("Reservations",reservationSchema);
//----------------------------------------->
app.post('/reserve_a_table', (req,res) => {
    let yourData = new Reservation(req.body);
    yourData.save().then(()=>{
        res.send("Data has been saved successfully!");
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(400).send("Data not saved due to some issues.");
    })
})
```

The frontend is **HTML** form with (input type = datetime-local)

I saw some related questions but couldn't find one for a user-entered date and time.
How should I progress? How can I modify the Date SchemaType such that it can in a way add 5:30hrs while saving in MongoDB so I can get the result I want i.e. time in Indian Standard Time?

Comment: Date and times in MongoDB are stored in UTC - **always and only**. You need to handle local times (actually the **display** of times) in your client application.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit so you mean to say I don't need to modify the time that is being stored in MongoDB and rather modify its display in the Java Application which I will be making to display the info stored in databases?

Comment: Correct, when you store values as `Date` object (what you should prefer always), then you cannot even modify it. If you need to preserve the user input time zone, then you must store it in a separate field.